# Prove that $X_t$ of the given SDE converges to $0$ a.s. as $t\uparrow 1$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider the SDE
$$X_t = -\int_0^t \frac{X_s}{1-s}ds + W_t$$
where $0\leq t < 1$, and $W_t$ is standard Brownian.

One can easily verify that this is a solution
$$X_t = (1-t)\int_0^t \frac{1}{1-s}dW_s$$
We wish to show that $\lim\limits_{t\uparrow 1} X_t = 0$ a.s. I can't seem to get this strong result, but I am able to show that $X_t \xrightarrow{L^2} 0$, which implies that there exists a subsequence that converges to $0$ a.s. 
$$E(X_t^2) = (1-t)^2\int_0^t \frac{1}{(1-s)^2} ds = t(1-t)$$ by Ito's Isometry.

Also, note that $X_t$ is not a martingale. It is possible that the question is wrong, but it does seem reasonable. Any ideas?

Comment: From your explicit formula for the solution it follows that $X_t$ is a continuous Gaussian process on $[0,1).$ Check that its covariance is $\mathbb{E}X_tX_s=\min(t,s)-ts,$ so that the distribution of the process coincides with the distribution of the Brownian bridge $B_t=W_t-tW_1,$ $0\leq t<1.$ For the latter process a.s. convergence $\lim_{t\to 1}B_t=0$ is obvious

Comment: Supposing one doesn't know about the brownian bridge, you may also (by a time change) write $\int_0^t \frac{1}{1-s}dW_s = B_{\frac{t}{1-t}}$ for some brownian motion $B$. By time-inversion, $u^{-1}B_u \to 0$ as $u \to \infty$. This kind of analysis may be useful when considering more general processes of the form $f(t)\int_0^t g(s)dW_s$, when there is no well-known process lurking.

Comment: Yes, this was what I was looking for @Shalop! Thanks, once again